# Make a reverse arrow in a li CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a simple li on a page:

```
<li tabindex="0" id="lidashboard" class="active">
  <a href="#/index/app/dashboard">
    <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-lg"></i>Dashboard
  </a>
</li>
```

Is it possible, with CSS, to make it finish as an arrow on right side. Something like:

[image: This li]

on hover li will have a right triangular border in white

Please help

Comment: https://1stwebdesigner.com/css-shapes/

Comment: try this : [Try This](https://jsfiddle.net/z5g4mjwd/12/)

Answer (score -1):

You can do as follows

```css
li{
    list-style: none;
}
.arrow{

    height: 100px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: red;
}

.arrow:hover{
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 68% 50%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 68% 50%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
        <ul>
            <li class="arrow"></li>
        </ul>
    
</body>

</html>
```

In order to play with clip-path values, look [here.](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

Comment: @raghav Does this answer answer your question?